# Creating PDF files using C# 4?

Tags: c#, .net, pdf

What library would you guys recommend I use to create a PDF document from a given collection of images?

I don't want to write text to the document or anything, just grab an Image object and save it to the PDF document.

Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I programmatically create a PDF in my .NET application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177/how-do-i-programmatically-create-a-pdf-in-my-net-application)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Migradoc](http://www.pdfsharp.net/)

Comment: hi GReg would you pls take a look at this one ....pls http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953471/system-crashing-when-the-print-button-is-clicked

Answer (score 1):

[Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/) can be used to quite easily create PDF files from images.

Please take a look at sample that shows how to [add images to PDF](https://github.com/BitMiracle/Docotic.Pdf.Samples/tree/master/Samples/Images/AddAndDrawImage).

Disclaimer: I work for the company.

Answer (score 1):

I recomend pdfSharp and Migradoc

http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/MainPage.ashx

Answer (score 0):

iText is a good library :
http://itextpdf.com/

Answer (score 0):

iTextsharp

http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/

http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Java/Creating-Simple-PDF-Files-With-iTextSharp/

Answer (score 0):

I like ABCPdf.net. You might look at PrinceXML too.